# Get Text with a PDF Reader?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdf-reader

How can I get only this simple text when I read a pdf?

`CLSAI10608`

This code always start with a `CLXXXXXXXX, LEN = 10`.

Code:

```
import PyPDF2
file = open('document.pdf', 'rb')
pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
pageobj = pdfreader.getPage(0)
print(pageobj.extractText())
```

output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA6I7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the regex pattern I came up with searchs for something starting with `CL` and then 8 non-whitespace characters. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HBw67U/1) provides a handy explanation.

```py
import re

string = r"""Detalle

Total

4040CL02

  Correccion de BL

CLSAI10608LV-PASSERO V0008-MBL : ISGA0F000

47.020"""

match = re.search(r"[C][L]\S{8}", string)
if match:
    code = match.group()
    print(code)
```

Output: `CLSAI10608`

So you'd want to replace `string` with `pageobj.extractText()`.